# Magnolia Throws Exception on Mobile

Tags: java, mobile, magnolia

I have a magnolia based website. It works properly when you brows it on PC, but it throws exception when I want to brows it using browsers on an android cellphone. I searched a lot but didn't find anything, Do you know what the cuase is and how can I solve it?

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
Failed to create proxy for sources [en, en, en] with types [interface java.lang.Cloneable, interface java.io.Serializable, class java.util.Locale]
Feb 20, 2016 4:49:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
org.apache.commons.proxy.exception.ProxyFactoryException: Proxy class cannot extend java.util.Locale as it is final.
        at org.apache.commons.proxy.factory.util.AbstractSubclassingProxyFactory.getSuperclass(AbstractSubclassingProxyFactory.java:134)
        at org.apache.commons.proxy.factory.cglib.CglibProxyFactory.createInvokerProxy(CglibProxyFactory.java:87)
        at org.apache.commons.proxy.ProxyFactory.createInvokerProxy(ProxyFactory.java:145)
        at info.magnolia.beanmerger.ProxyBasedBeanMerger.mergeBean(ProxyBasedBeanMerger.java:83)
        at info.magnolia.beanmerger.BeanMergerBase.merge(BeanMergerBase.java:77)
        at info.magnolia.beanmerger.ProxyBasedBeanMerger$MergeInvoker.invoke(ProxyBasedBeanMerger.java:138)
        at org.apache.commons.proxy.factory.cglib.CglibProxyFactory$InvokerBridge.invoke(CglibProxyFactory.java:116)
        at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.DefaultI18nContentSupport$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e8a68ee5.determineLocale(<generated>)
        at info.magnolia.module.site.i18n.SiteI18nContentSupport.determineLocale(SiteI18nContentSupport.java:104)
        at info.magnolia.module.site.i18n.SiteI18nContentSupport$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5ad55914.determineLocale(<generated>)
        at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:59)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:84)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:80)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:127)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:87)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.module.devicedetection.filter.DeviceDetectionFilter.doFilter(DeviceDetectionFilter.java:71)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:143)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:108)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails trying to determine locale for your request. You might want to examine request headers to see what is different there between your cell phone and desktop. I would suspect that cell phone requests site in different locale than the desktop does.
Other possibility is that the page you are trying to access has a component that is enabled only on mobile, but disabled on desktop. You might want to check that.
Last but not least, I would try to upgrade to the latest version of Magnolia. Locale should not be proxied and I would expect that if any version was released with that issue, someone would have ran into it rather fast and I would expect fix for it to be already out too in that case. If not, you might want to log the issue with Magnolia at http://jira.magnolia-cms.com

HTH,
Jan